# Alertify is executing before confirmation?

Tags: jquery, alertify

I decided to modify and style i little bit my code with Alertify. My old code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ask').click(function(){
    var answer = confirm('<?php echo $this->translate('Delete route?'); ?>');   
    return answer;
});
```

When I press ok a php script runs and deletes the record. Javascript return true or false.

The problem I have with Alertify is that I even cant press ok or cancel, my php script runs before that. Here is the code:

```
$(".ask").click(function(event){
alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

I saw some people with similar problems and I saw that I need to use prevent defaults (it makes sense) The code:

```
$(".ask").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        return true; // submit form skipping jQuery bound handler
    } else {

    }
});
```

});

In that case the php script doesnt run before i press ok/cancel but it doesnt run too when i press one of the buttons. Nothing happens.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running into the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.  In the original code, execution of all JavaScript is paused while the `confirm` dialog is open, so you can directly use the return value from it.  However, when you use `alertify.confirm`, it doesn't pause execution of the script, so the click handler returns immediately and any code around it will also run - ie the code to invoke your php script.  When you attempt to `return true;` from inside the `alertify.confirm` callback function, you're returning from that inner function to the `alertify` code, not returning from your outer click handler function.

What you need to do is start to work with the callback methods available, rather than against it - I would suggest restructuring your code as follows.  Following confirmation that `.ask` is an `a` tag, the following should work:

```
$(".ask").click(function(event){
  var loc = $(this).attr('href');
  alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        document.location.href = loc;
    }
  });
  //prevent link from being followed immediately on click
  return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 but as other way - instead of callback function - you can use `$.Deferred()`.

Comment: will not work check here form will submit not wait for ok or cancel http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/36/

Comment: Assuming that `.ask` is a form submit button, which hasn't actually been specified anywhere, simply turn it into a normal, non-submitting button.  No need to prevent the default action either then, which could in turn lead to other unwanted issues elsewhere as more complexity is introduced into the page.

Comment: @user3819192 just add `return false` at the end of click handler: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/38/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now things are more clear but i am not sure what i must do. Btw i thing that i forgot to say that .ask is <a href> which leads to zend controller, there the delete is made.

Comment: @LubomirBorisov so you do not want to prevent default behaviour when user clicked "Ok" in alertify?